# Is there a way to open DRM protected books?

Tags: 11.10, calibre

Is there a way to open a DRM protected book that I have purchased in Ubuntu 11.10 64bit. I also have Calibre installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question but I found a couple of solutions. The first was to download "Adobe Digital Editions" using the "Play on Linux" Wine program. The Adobe website wont let you download it directly but it will let you download the "Windows Installer" if you click on having trouble downloading the program. It was almost automatic using the "Play on Linux" version from the developers website plus it has a step by step tutorial on how to use it for people that are afraid of "Wine," like me. The second solution is to go to https://read.amazon.com/ it's an on-line version of "kindle" that will allow you to read DRM protected books and it has an off-line reading mode included, it basically turns your browser into a "kindle," the only drawback to this solution is that you have to purchase the book from Amazon.