# Foliate reader is stuck on a URLLink file while opening a DRM protected ebook

Tags: 20.04, wine, ebooks

Ubuntu 20.04
Wine 5.0
q4wine installer
Adobe digital Essentials (working)
Foliate reader

I'm a noob.  I wanted an ebook reader.  On "it's FOSS" I found a list of the 10 best.  Foliate looked good.  Then I went to ebooks.com and bought a book.  They sent setup.exe (ADE) and URLLink.ascm (the link to my book at ebooks).  Before I knew I didn't know anything I dragged the URLLink over to Foliate and it's still there,  I can't get it off.  How do I delete Foliate and start over again?  What directory do my ebooks use?  I can use Adobe Digital Edition to read  the book but the presentation isn't that great.  Anyone have a better recommendation for a reader?  Thanks

Comment: does the ebook you purchased have DRM?

Comment: Foliate can open .epub files. It cannot open DRM protected ebooks. The ebook you obtained is certainly DRM protected. https://support.7switch.com/hc/en-us/articles/208191235-What-to-do-with-my-URLLink-acsm-file- 
Also see https://stallman.org/ebooks.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to open DRM protected books?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92033/is-there-a-way-to-open-drm-protected-books)

Answer (score 0):

Foliate supports the following formats (Source: [Readme](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/#readme))

> ```
> EPUB (.epub, .epub3)
> Kindle (.azw, .azw3) and Mobipocket (.mobi)
> FictionBook (.fb2, .fb2.zip)
> Comic book archive (.cbr, .cbz, .cbt, .cb7)
> Plain text (.txt)
> ```

You cannot open DRM protected ebooks with Foliate. Adobe controls this proprietary format, and the only way to access these books is to use Adobe Digital edition. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92033/is-there-a-way-to-open-drm-protected-books) answer for more details.

There are tools to remove DRM from a URLLink.acsm file, but they are not legal, and you would not find them on this site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!